# How can I split the body field to insert content between the first and the second paragraph?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a node which shows content from the body field. I want to add a another paragraph or a block between between the first and the second paragraph, after the first `</p>` and before the second `<p>` tag.

But in my template to output the body there's only `{{ content.body }}`.

Drupal 7 had something like block in block. How can I do the same in Drupal 8?

Comment: You are probably referring to https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/block-in-block/insert-ads-within-article-bodies, right? And your question actually is **How can I insert ads within article bodies**?, right?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue, using solution below

```
    {% set Paragraphs = node.body.value|split('</p>') %}
  {% set paragraphHalf = (Paragraphs|length / 2)|round %}
  
  {% if paragraphHalf %}
    {% for paragraph in Paragraphs %}
      {% if paragraphHalf == 1 or loop.index % paragraphHalf == 1 -%}
        
      {% endif %}
      {{ paragraph|raw }}

      {% if loop.last or loop.index % paragraphHalf == 0 -%}
      {{ insert item }}
      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}
```